# SQLite Query for Higher Integer with particular Date

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

Attached is my data format from SQLite

```
Date, Stock_Code, Yahoo_Stock_Code, Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume
('2016-11-28', 1, '0001.HK', 94.55, 95.2, 94.1, 94.6, 94.6, 5909700) 
('2016-11-28', 2, '0002.HK', 74.65, 75.45, 74.6, 75, 74.43, 3050500) 
('2016-11-28', 3, '0003.HK', 14.5, 14.6, 14.4, 14.44, 14.44, 8309500) 
('2016-11-25', 1, '0001.HK', 95.05, 95.55, 94.6, 95.1, 95.1, 3661200) 
('2016-11-25', 2, '0002.HK', 74.45, 74.45, 74.05, 74.3, 73.735, 1434600) 
('2016-11-25', 3, '0003.HK', 14.44, 14.46, 14.36, 14.46, 14.46, 5663800) 
('2016-11-24', 1, '0001.HK', 95.85, 96.05, 95.05, 95.6, 95.6, 2756900) 
('2016-11-24', 2, '0002.HK', 74.2, 74.3, 73.9, 74.05, 73.487, 1401800) 
('2016-11-24', 3, '0003.HK', 14.38, 14.46, 14.34, 14.36, 14.36, 7738800) 
('2016-11-23', 1, '0001.HK', 96.6, 96.9, 95.95, 96.2, 96.2, 3678500) 10
('2016-11-23', 2, '0002.HK', 74.45, 75, 74.15, 74.55, 73.983, 3155800) 11
('2016-11-23', 3, '0003.HK', 14.36, 14.5, 14.34, 14.38, 14.38, 8022700) 
('2016-11-22', 1, '0001.HK', 96.3, 96.8, 95.65, 96.5, 96.5, 3567000) 13
('2016-11-22', 2, '0002.HK', 73.35, 74.4, 73.35, 74.05, 73.487, 3841700) 
('2016-11-22', 3, '0003.HK', 14.42, 14.42, 14.32, 14.36, 14.36, 16001000)
```

With 3 stock code in mind, I want to create a query which can tell me the close of 3 stocks on 2016-11-28 is higher than the close of  3 stocks in 2016-11-22. Furthermore, I wish that I could put this query into a list for further analysis.

I am new to SQLite, so far I have not tried much. I can only make a simple query as follows:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Historical_Table "
        "WHERE Date BETWEEN '2016-11-22' AND '2016-11-28' "
        "AND Stock_Code IN ('1', '2','3' ) ORDER BY Date DESC ")
```

Please advise if I need to make the query individually for each stock or if I can make all the query in one go. Thank you very much

Comment: Please show your expected output based on this sample data (`2016-11-22` does not even appear as a data point).  Do you want to compare the _average_ prices from one date against another, or something else?

Comment: And also show what you've tried so far

Comment: You still haven't showed us the output you expect.  Your current query isn't very helpful, because you already know that it won't give you what you want.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for taking your time. Let say the answer is the price of 2016-11-28 is higher than the price of 2016-11-22 for 1 and 3. I expect the output would be like: (1,3) in python  list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
       (SELECT Close FROM yourTable WHERE Stock-Code = 1 AND Product = '2016-11-28') >
       (SELECT Close FROM yourTable WHERE Stock-Code = 1 AND Product = '2016-11-22')
       THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for your comment. Yes, the statement work fine. I am just wondering if the Stock_Code can have multiple stocks code query instead of one.

Comment: @HankPang Sure, you could use `WHERE Stock-Code IN (1, 2, 3, ...)` for example.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, I tried that (WHERE Stock-Code IN (1, 2, 3, ...)). For example, I have two stock codes and there are two outcomes (No. 1 stock_code is a yes and No. 2 stock_code is a no). When i make a query, and the answer comes out as yes for the first stock code and then there will be no answer for the second stock code.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that WHERE ... IN clause only accepts a limited number of values (which differs from engine to engine).